# How to align check box and span with text and googleapi symbol?

Tags: html, css

I have table with four cells. Each cell has input filed and text with icon. I would like to vertically align all three elements on the same height. Here is example of my code:

```css
.tbl-checks {
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="tbl-checks">
  <theaed>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </theaed>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="1" />
          <span class="checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 1</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" value="2" />
          <span class="checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 2</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check3" id="check3" value="3" />
          <span class="data-checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 3</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check4" id="check4" value="4" />
          <span class="data-checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 4</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see in my example Symbol, Text and Checkbox are not aligned. Is there a way to accomplish them to be on the same vertical height with CSS?

Answer (score 2):

add flex display and center the items by setting `align-items` to center

```
td, td>span{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.tbl-checks {
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td, td>span{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="tbl-checks">
  <theaed>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </theaed>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="1" />
          <span class="checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 1</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" value="2" />
          <span class="checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 2</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check3" id="check3" value="3" />
          <span class="data-checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 3</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check4" id="check4" value="4" />
          <span class="data-checks"><i class="material-icons" style="color:##ffc107">warning</i> Text 4</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If I have long text in the span then check box will stay on one line and span will go under. How to keep them on the same line? Should I try to apply flex on td element? Not sure if that is proper way to do it. Or maybe move input element inside of the span?